# synchronise git repo between two ssh machines

Tags: git, ssh

I'm beginner using git so afer hours configuring ssh between host and a virtual machine

I try to use git to synchronise data (code) between:

So Basically on Host :

I have a folder named MYFIRSTPROJECT, inside this folder i do :

`git init` (only once)

then on VM side i do:

```
git clone  git+ssh://admin@192.168.1.1/z/Project/MYFIRSTPROJECT/.git
```

--> this works the content appears

so I try to modify the code of a file MYFIRSTPROJECT/exemple.java on VM side and then I do :

```
git add --all

git commit -m 'my first commit'

git push git+ssh://admin@192.168.1.1/z/Project/MYFIRSTPROJECT/.git
```

Nothing change on Host side. I'm probably missing something but I expect to the file on host machines got refresh and the change made getting applied.

Otherwise when i'm doing a change on Host side (after the git clone on VM side) and i go back to VM side and i do a:

```
git pull
```

on this way the changed are properly apply

Thanks for your help

Comment: Did `git push` return errors like `error: refusing to update checked out branch:` and `[remote rejected] foo -> foo (branch is currently checked out)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the working tree is not modified by a push.

The best practice is to create locally a **[bare repository](https://www.saintsjd.com/2011/01/what-is-a-bare-git-repository/)**, and put in it a [`post-receive` hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#_server_side_hooks) which can be configured to execute any command you need.
Like going to your actual local repository (the one you created) and doing a `git pull` (to update the working tree from the commits you pushed to the bare repository from your VM.

So locally:

```bash
cd /d Z:
cd Project
git clone --bare MYFIRSTPROJECT MYFIRSTPROJECT.git
cd MYFIRSTPROJECT
git remote add origin ..\MYFIRSTPROJECT.git
```

Create a `Z:\Project\Project\MYFIRSTPROJECT.git\hooks\post-receive` file (eol as LF, not CRLF) with:

```bash
cd /Z/Project/MYFIRSTPROJECT
git pull
```

And from your VM:

```bash
cd /path/to/MYFIRSTPROJECT
git remote set-url origin  git+ssh://admin@192.168.1.1/z/Project/MYFIRSTPROJECT.git
# not /.git, but MYFIRSTPROJECT.git, which by naming convention, references a bare repo
```

Comment: Thank you so so much it works perfectly. Only thing , it's Ive now an extra folder in project: "MYFIRSTPROJECT.git"

Comment: @ThomasSan Well done! The extra folder is expected: it is the bare repository you can push to.